# optimize the function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, modeling

I have tried many times taking different initial values of `c`. I did not get optimum values of `c` using function `fminsearch`. I have found more error between simulated and measured values of `sigma`. Please help me: how can optimize my function?

```
clc
close all
clear all    

syms c sigma est_bio mea_bio

sigma=[-15.1015 -13.7879    -13.0576    -12.7818    -12.3839    -11.7587    -11.1756    -10.6291    -9.9176];    
mea_bio=[0.181  0.204   0.529   0.632   1.059   1.533   1.934   1.977   1.861];

%%%  create model function q with parameters    
 q = @(c, mea_bio) ((c(1)/(-2*c(2))).*(1-exp(2*c(2).*mea_bio))+c(3).*exp(2*c(2).*mea_bio))     

%// create the desired error-functions for minimization    
h = @(c) sum((q(c, mea_bio) - sigma).^2); %// default minimizaton function    
c= [-.05 -.0500 -.0500]; % an initial guess   
[p_fit_e, r_e] = fminsearch(h, c) % Optimize
est_q = ((c(1)/(-2*c(2))).*(1-exp(2*c(2).*mea_bio))+c(3).*exp(2*c(2).*mea_bio))
err=est_q-sigma
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you define `c`, `sigma` `est_bio` and `mea_bio` as symbolic variables? It doesn't make sense. This is a numerical optimization, no need to involve symbolic computations. Remove that line from your code and it should work:

```
syms c sigma est_bio mea_bio
```